# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS upgrade problem

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I want do_release_upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS but I receive update errors:

```
Error during update
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.
W:The repository 'https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu
bionic-infra-security Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data
from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore
potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for
repository creation and user configuration details., W:The repository
'https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates Release'
does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be
authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See
apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
details., E:Failed to fetch
https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/bionic-infra-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages
, E:Failed to fetch
https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/bionic-infra-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or
old ones used instead.
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon May  3 12:47:38 2021) ===***
```

How can I fix this?
Can I still do_release_upgrade after 30th april 2021?

greetz,
Timo

Comment: Remove the `esm.ubuntu.com` sources (they are invalid for *bionic* as it's still in *standard* support) and try again.

Comment: We stopped answering questions about 16.04 when Standard Support ended. You are asking a support question about a release of Ubuntu that we no longer provide support for. If you encounter further problems after you fix your sources, then back up your data and install (not upgrade to) the newer release of Ubuntu. Next time, mark your calendar so you don't miss the window.

Comment: do you mean in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: @Timo Yes, it can be by editing it but it's much easier in Software&Updates > Other software.

Comment: esm.ubuntu.com is not in the  /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: it uses nl.archive

Comment: I now removed esm files from :/etc/apt/sources.list.d and that was the solution
THX for support!!

Comment: @karel  I don't think that technically applies (yet), in fact xenial's repository has not yet been closed (for standard support) as the Ubuntu Release team are awaiting a final grub+shim package to be built & placed in 'main' before they finally close it up for *standard* support (steve.langasek).  Builds are currently backlogged so that may not occur till tomorrow (but once done archive will be closed)